# React error 185- I know the issue but how can I call setState once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's the relevant code-

```
CONFIG.theme.activeScheme ? react.createElement(SortBox, {
            onChange: this.updateColourScheme.bind(this),
            onnewschemes: this.setState({}),
            // TODO: Make this compatible with the changes to the theme install process: need to create a method to update the scheme options without a full reload.
            sortBoxOptions: generateSchemesOptions(CONFIG.theme.schemes),
            // It doesn't work when I directly use CONFIG.theme.activeScheme in the sortBySelectedFn
            // because it hardcodes the value into the fn
            sortBySelectedFn: (a) => a.key === this.getActiveScheme(),
        }) : null,
```

My preferred end result is to be able to reload JUST the sortbox component using an via the onnewschemes event(I pretty much need to refresh all of the options within a little drop down method from outside the render itself.)
The event dispatcher i have looks like so:

```
const schemeSelector = document.querySelector("div.marketplace-header > div > div");
        const newSchemeEvent = new CustomEvent("newschemes", {
            bubbles: true,
            detail: { schemes: () => parsedSchemes },
        });
        schemeSelector.dispatchEvent(newSchemeEvent);
```

Comment: Using the setstate method to update the options in the sort box now, however, I still need to figure out how to parse the detail: argument in the event into the this.setState in the render.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, apparently changing the state automatically updates it so there was no need for a custom event in the first place, just needed to do some coding things.